# Delete records with eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent

I'm starting to use eloquent as my ORM.
my old database has a column called deleted but eloquent uses a column name deleted_at with a timestamp.

is there a way to consider a record soft deleted if deleted = 1 or deleted_at = timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel, look into this documentation
https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletes.html
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class YourModelName extends MainModel
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    const DELETED_AT = 'deleted '; // your custom column name
}
```